# While inheriting values from another functions: 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data

Tags: c++

The problem statement specifies the type of return values has to be as it is.

I am getting the error 'argument': conversion from 'double' to 'int', possible loss of data on the line double temp = valueGeneration(min * sc, max * sc);

I know it's because the double value is received by the int value as parameters. But is there a way to get around it and have no warnings in the code?

I am not allowed to change the return type and the parameter type to double.

```
int valueGeneration(int min, int max) {
    int range = max - min + 1;
    int num = rand() % range + min;

    return num;
}

double doubleValueGeneration(double min, double max){
    double sc = 10;
    double temp = valueGeneration(min * sc, max * sc);
    double num = temp / sc;

    return num;
```

Comment: please include the complete error message in the quesiton. It should be a warning, not an error

Comment: Have you tried just casting each argument to `int`?

Comment: "While inheriting values from another functions" - I don't see anything about "inheriting" in the question. You're passing the result of computing expressions in one function as arguments to another function, which has different parameter types... there's nothing about "inheriting" there.

Comment: As said, you might lose data, so `int(temp)` might be different than (initial) `valueGeneration(min * sc, max * sc)`. apply to big numbers. in the same way as, for some value of (double) `d`, `d == d + 1`.

Comment: It is warning, but as per the assignment we have to get rid of the warnings as well.

Comment: A cast will achieve that.

Comment: A cast will eliminate the warning, but it might not always be the right thing to do. Heed the warning about information loss. `double`s can hold much larger numbers than `int`s can and can also handle fractions. The warning is just making sure you are aware of the potential for loss.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the lack of context, I don't see the reason behind this code, but instead of a `static_cast`, an `lround` should be a clearer solution to achieve what you want. (see: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round)

```
int valueGeneration(int min, int max) {
    int range = max - min + 1;
    int num = rand() % range + min;

    return num;
}

double doubleValueGeneration(double min, double max){
    double sc = 10;
    double temp = valueGeneration(std::lround(min * sc), std::lround(max * sc));
    double num = temp / sc;

    return num;
```

Let's note that `sizeof(int) <= sizeof(long)`, so depending on your OS/compiler, this can also result in a (different) warning, In this case just `static_cast<int>`.

Comment: Please note that a cast and `lround` do different things.  A cast truncates (e.g. 42.9 -> 42) whereas `lround` rounds to the nearest integer (e.g. 42.9 -> 43).  OP, your choice